# Cómo crear número hexadecimal aleatorio de X dígitos?

Tags: php

¿Cómo se puede crear un número hexadecimal aleatorio, por ejemplo de 5 dígitos?
Es decir algo como: A31D4.

Haciendo lo siguiente:

```
$mirand = dechex(rand());
```

me genera números aleatorios pero a veces son de 3 dígitos y la mayoría de veces son de 4, nunca de 5.

Comment: con un `do {
    $mirand = dechex(rand());
} while (strlen ($mirand )  != 5 ); `

Comment: me salen todos de 8 dígitos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He creado la siguiente función, la cual recibe como parámetro el número de dígitos que debe tener el código hexadecimal.

```
    <?php

function hexadecimalAzar($caracteres){

    $caracteresPosibles = "0123456789abcdef";
    $azar = '';

    for($i=0; $i<$caracteres; $i++){

        $azar .= $caracteresPosibles[rand(0,strlen($caracteresPosibles)-1)];

    }

    return $azar;

}

echo hexadecimalAzar(5);
```

Comment: me gusta tu respuesta pero no me gusta los "magic numbers". Pon en vez de `15`, la longitud del string ... (mi opinión , claro)

Comment: Tienes razón, lo acabo de editar @lois6b

Answer (score 7):

Esta solución siempre me ha gustado, puede que utilice un método no tan ortodoxo, pero me ha funcionado, es simple y corta:

```
substr(md5(rand()), 0, 5);
```

Puedes ingresar un rango de valores en `rand()` si lo deseas.

Answer (score 2):

Para un número par de caracteres, algo corto:

```
function hexadecimalAzar($caracteres){
    $bytes = random_bytes($caracteres/2);
    return bin2hex($bytes);
}
```

Para el caso más general habría que escribir algo más de código.

---

**Editado**:

...y el caso general:

```
function hexadecimalAzar($caracteres){
    $bytes = random_bytes($caracteres/2 + 1);
    return substr(bin2hex($bytes), 0, $caracteres);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con Php7 yo lo haría así:

```
function decimal_hex ():string
    {
      $n = dechex(rand(1, 100));

      return $n;
    }


    echo decimal_hex();
```

Ya que Php cuenta con función nativa para transformar un decimal a hexadecimal ( [link documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.dechex.php)), simplemente obtienes un decimal al azar y lo pasas a hexadecimal.

Si quieres n valores, invocas la función dentro de un bucle:

```
 $n = 100;
    while ($n)
    {
      echo decimal_hex() . '</br>';
      $n--;
    }
```

Pero ya depende de tu criterio cómo usar la función. Igual puede quedar así:

```
function decimal_hex ():string
  {
    return dechex(rand(1, 100));
  }
```

Y por último, el **:string** es una característica nueva de Php7 con la que indicas el tipo de valor de retorno, en este caso string porque puede devolver letras y números.

Saludos.